# MySQL: Return all rows with same ID but filter by a different field

Tags: mysql, sql

In my application, I have a table that identifies resources (i.e. pictures) by their id. Said resources have also been "tagged" (field1). i.e. Picture 3 in the table below is tagged with both 'A' and 'B'. Whereas Picture 1 is tagged with only 'A' and Picture 2 is tagged with only 'B'.

Here is my "tagging" table:

```
+--------------+
|  id | field1 |
+--------------+
|   1 |      A |
|   2 |      B |
|   3 |      A |
|   3 |      B |
+--------------+
```

Note: The id's are neither unique nor auto-incrementing.

Problem: I want to return all pictures tagged as 'B', but I do not want to return any that are tagged as 'A'.

SELECT id from pictures
WHERE field1 = 'B';

Returns:

```
+-----+
|  id |
+-----+
|   2 |
|   3 |
+-----+
```

This is not want I want, because it includes Picture 3 which is also tagged with 'A' (in the row immediately preceding [3, B] in the original table)

I want:

```
+-----+
|  id |
+-----+
|   2 |
+-----+
```

Comment: How can you have a duplicate Id?

Comment: @genespos it is not a unique Id.

Comment: Define 'previous row' - or does it not matter that the row is 'previous'?

Comment: @Strawberry: the row immediately before [3, B] in the original table.

Comment: @Strawberry: updated the OP hopefully for clarity. Anyway I found my answer. Thanks to everyone who provided a working solution I wish I could accept them all!

Comment: Curiously, no one provided (what would historically have been) the most straightforward answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are two methods:

exists subclause:

```
SELECT id 
from pictures as pictures1
WHERE field1 = 'B' 
and not exists ( 
     select * 
     from pictures as picutures2 
     where pictures2.id = pictures1.id
     and pictures2.field1 = 'A');
```

left join:

```
Select pictures1.id 
from pictures as pictures1
left join pictures as picutures2 on
     pictures2.id = pictures1.id
     and pictures2.field1 = 'A'
where  pictures1.field1 = 'B'
and pictures2.ID is null -- this line eliminates records where the join fails; note that if you have this line, you must not put any other pictures2 references in this where clause
```

;

Answer (score 0):

You started well with your request. Just unselect rows where field1 is A. :

```
SELECT id from pictures WHERE field1 = 'B' AND id NOT IN(
    SELECT id from pictures WHERE field1 = 'A'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve your desired result using some aggregation in a single query

```
select id
from table1
group by id
having sum(field1 = 'B') > 0
and sum(field1 = 'A') = 0
```

[`DEMO`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d556d/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id
FROM pictures
GROUP BY id
HAVING (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT fuild1)) = 'B'
```